# What is the ideal size to encode X265 by FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, x264, x265

If I have 500 Megabytes of video size, what is the reduced ideal size to convert video from x264 to x265 without losing quality using FFmpeg?

Another example:

Let me tell you that the video I want to convert is anime 24 minutes in length and blue ray, and the size is 1500 megabytes. I reduce it to 150 Megabytes by using FFmpeg; please give me a rough answer. Is there a loss in quality or not?

Comment: this is not something we can answer for you. Sorry. you will have to figure out what is right for you. the video in question has a big impact on this question. for instance animation tends to be much easier to shrink without noticeable loss of video quality. you also need to make your decisions about audio tracks and channels, subs, etc. there is just too much to give a single answer, especially to a 1-sentence question that provides almost no detail.

Comment: You are the only one that can assess the quality of the output, using your eyes :)... Don't forget however that a video can look nice on a small screen, and poor on a large screen. To **me**, h264 videos with a bitrate of 3Mb/s look good on a regular size TV, or h265 videos with a bitrate of 2Mb/s. But it's only to me. 2Mb/s means 900MB per hour.

Comment: All answers are not good.

Comment: Maybe because the question does not have good answers.

Comment: Give me a specific answer, please, and do not give me an unclear answer

Comment: If you want a specific answer, then ask a specific, focused, question. If you just want to know if there is a "loss a quality" when reencoding a video with a lossy compression algorithm, then the definite answer is "yes, always".

Comment: How can I determine the quality of a video using numerical measurements? Is there a program that can assist me in doing this, please?

Comment: Yes FFMPEG can compute the size of an output for a given input video and chosen options, by creating an output of the size that it is. You don't like this answer, but it is THE answer. There are too many factors, small and large, that impact this. The math problem IS run by Ffmpeg as it encodes your video.

Comment: @krm simple answer: you can't determine the quality of a video before creating the video. Once created, there are numerical measurements that can be performed: https://ottverse.com/calculate-psnr-vmaf-ssim-using-ffmpeg/ , but 1) numerical measurements do not reflect well the perceptual quality and 2) the perceptual quality is not absolute and entirely depends on how you are watching the video (on a phone under the sun is not the same than on a 80" TV in a dark room)

Comment: @PierU thank you, Mr PierU, for your professional answer

Comment: @music2myear thank you so much

Comment: All the responses are outstanding and positive.